# How to use postgres stored procedures with Node pg package? or without pg package in Node Expressjs applications

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

How to use postgres stored procedures with Node pg package? or without pg package in Node Expressjs applications. I am able to run inline queries but no idea how to use stored procedures.

Comment: Like this: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#functions--procedures

Answer (score 0):

postgres uses functions instead of procedures. if you want to exec a function ignoring return, you can create it with no return, or run it by `PERFORM`, instead of `SELECT`...
In all other aspects running functions is same as running queries:

```
environments=# select * from now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2015-07-03 08:19:30.096488+02
(1 row)

environments=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2015-07-03 08:19:40.260368+02
(1 row)

environments=# do
environments-# $$
environments$# begin
environments$# perform now();
environments$# end;
environments$# $$
environments-# ;
DO
```